# Add spacing between buttons in LinearLayout that's inside a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview, spacing

I've attempted to change the X position of the buttons, it works but the buttons then end up getting caught off by the HorizontalScrollView. All I want to do is add spacing between the buttons.

Here is the code I'm using to display the buttons programmatically:

```
@TargetApi(21)
private void loadProfiles() {
    HorizontalScrollView scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) scrollView.findViewById(R.id.scrollLinear);
    if(getFilesDir().listFiles().length != 0) {
        for(File file : getFilesDir().listFiles()) {
            ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);
            button.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            button.setY(35);
            button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundedbutton, getTheme()));
            layout.addView(button);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the HorizontalScrollView:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bar"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollLinear"></LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here is a picture of what the buttons currently look like:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cX13.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
        layoutParams.setMargins(10,0,0,10);
        button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        button.setY(35);
        button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundedbutton, getTheme()));
        layout.addView(button);
```

This should work

Comment: I tried using `ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(150, 150);
                params.setMargins(10, 0 ,0 ,10);
                button.setLayoutParams(params);` but that didn't work either

Comment: Have you tried changing ActionBar.LayoutParams to LinearLayout.LayoutParams ? Shouldn't matter, though.

Comment: The correct usage was the LinearLayout.LayoutParams, yes. Thank you

Comment: No problem. I've edited the answer. Would you consider marking it as correct? (: